# change() fires only when losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I currently using the change function from jQuery. The change event is only fired when i click outside the textfield. So when i insert a text in my textbox nothing is happening but when i lose the focus on the textfield the event fires.
No i want to fire the event without having to click outside the textfield.

this is my code:

```
 jQuery("#customfield_10000").change(function(){
            crmAccount = jQuery(this).val();
            alert(crmAccount);
            lijstAccounts = [];

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/papa/jQuery/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/searchAccounts.php?jsonp_callback=?",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        jsonp: "jsonp_callback",
                        data: {
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            name_startsWith: jQuery(this).val()
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                 jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                                                            lijstAccounts.push(item.label);
                                                            jQuery('#customfield_10000').trigger(
                                                                'setSuggestions',
                                                            { result : textext.itemManager().filter(lijstAccounts, query) }
                                                            );              
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.value    
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

             });
```

Comment: try pressing enter with your current code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KeyUp event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/):

```
$("#abcd").keyup(function(event) {
     //code
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should handle the `input` (non-IE) or `propertchange` (IE-only) or `keyup` (won't catch pastes or drag&drop) events.